# Woocommerce | I want to the button 'Add to Cart' on the (all) product-page changed by just 'open product' button

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Woocommerce | I want to the button 'Add to Cart' on the (all) product-page changed by just 'open product' button.

I know people can click on the image or on the title but I also want a need button (instead of add to cart) to open the product.

Can you guys help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function wc_shop_open_product() {
    echo '<a class="button demo_button" href="'.get_the_permalink().'">Open product</a>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'wc_shop_open_product' );
```

Comment: Where do I need to put this? 

I put it now on functions.php but it wont work. :(

Comment: sorry I placed something wrong copy my code again

Comment: In functions.php? Cause still nothing changed. I only have the button 'add to cart'.

Comment: I see what it's doing. It makes an extra button when I open the product itself.
But the button needs to be on the page where all the products are.